# what is the use of Object handler in LocaleChangeInterceptor.preHandle

Tags: java, spring, locale

I am worried about the parameter passed (Object handler) to LocaleChangeInterceptor.preHandle().

When I am calling the preHandle(), I can pass the current request, response objects. But where from shall I get the handler.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, a `handler` in Spring nomenclature refers to the instance of the `@Controller` implementation that is handling the current request.

In the case of the `LocaleChangeInterceptor`, the handler parameter is not used so you can pass whatever. However, you should pass the controller instance if possible, to adhere to convention.

EDIT: why are you calling it in the first place? It's supposed to be used has an interceptor and only be called by the Spring MVC framework.

Comment: Thanks,
but I don't want an interceptor to call it. I want to call it from my controller. Then what I should do ?

Comment: @user1688343 You can still wire it and call it from your controller. It's just not how you're *supposed* to do it. Just look at the source-code for the `LocaleChangeInterceptor` and you'll see how it works, it's not very complicated.